# RingCentral OAuth with Django

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I'm working through RingCentral's Authorization Flow Quick Start App using Django. This required making a few changes to the [Flask code provided](https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication/quick-start#python), but most of the flow is working. The index page sends me to RingCentral login, which then sends me back to the test page as it should. But when I click on any of the three links on that page I get the same error:

```
AttributeError at /test/
'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here's the Django view that handles the test page (slightly modified from the Flask code provided):

```py
def test(request):
    platform = SyncConfig.rcsdk.platform()
    platform.auth().set_data(request.session['sessionAccessToken'])
    if platform.logged_in() == False:
        return index(request)
        api = request.GET.get('api')
    if api == "extension":
        resp = platform.get("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension")
        return resp.response()._content
    elif api == "extension-call-log":
        resp = platform.get("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/call-log")
        return resp.response()._content
    elif api == "account-call-log":
        resp = platform.get("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log")
        return resp.response()._content
    else:
        return render(request, 'sync/test.html')
```

And sync/test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <b><a href="/logout">Logout</a></b>
  <h2>Call APIs</h2>
  <ul>
      <li><a href="/test?api=extension">Read Extension Info</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test?api=extension-call-log">Read Extension Call Log</a></li>
      <li><a href="/test?api=account-call-log">Read Account Call Log</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone setup a Django authorization flow for RingCentral and can show me where this is breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Simply returning `resp.response()._content` from a view was causing Django problems. I wrote a simple view to display the data and returned the rendered template instead, with `resp.response()._content` included in the context.

```py
def test(request):
    platform = SyncConfig.rcsdk.platform()
    platform.auth().set_data(request.session['sessionAccessToken'])
    if platform.logged_in() == False:
        return index(request)
    api = request.GET.get('api')
    if api == "extension":
        resp = platform.get("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension")
        content = json.loads(resp.response()._content)
        return render(request, 'sync/response.html', {'content': content})
    elif api == "extension-call-log":
        resp = platform.get("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/call-log")
        content = json.loads(resp.response()._content)
        return render(request, 'sync/response.html', {'content': content})
    elif api == "account-call-log":
        resp = platform.get("/restapi/v1.0/account/~/call-log")
        content = json.loads(resp.response()._content)
        return render(request, 'sync/response.html', {'content': content})
    else:
        return render(request, 'sync/test.html')
```

And here's `sync/response.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <b><a href="/logout">Logout</a></b>
    <h2>API Response</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for k, v in content.items %}
            <li>{{ k }}: {{ v }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```